# Run time error assigning cv::Mat element value using cv::Mat::at

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, matrix

In the following code I would like to assign a values to elements of a Mat variable in a loop. I get the runtime error below.

```cpp
pair<Mat, Mat> meshgrid(vector<int> x, vector<int> y) {

    int sx = (int)x.size();
    int sy = (int)y.size();
    
    Mat xmat = Mat::ones(sy, sx, CV_16U);
    Mat ymat = Mat::ones(sy, sy, CV_16U);

    for (int i = 0; i < sx; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < sy; j++) {
            xmat.at<int>(i, j) = j;  // <------- here is place of error.
            cout << j << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < sx; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < sy; j++) {
            ymat.at<int>(i, j) = i;  // <------- here is place of error.
            cout << j << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return make_pair(xmat, ymat);
}
```

This picture when debuging;

[image]

This is the run time error I get:

```
OpenCV(...) Error: Assertion failed
(((((sizeof(size_t)<<28)|0x8442211) >> ((traits::Depth<_Tp>::value) &
((1 << 3) - 1))*4) & 15) == elemSize1()) in cv::Mat::at, file
...\include\opencv2\core\mat.inl.hpp, line 1108
```

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: You're programming in C++. Please don't add other irrelevant language tags.

Comment: changing `ymat.at<int>(i, j) = i;` with `ymat.at<uchar>cv::Point(i, j) = i;`

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk - I think there are some more problems in the code in addition to the usage of `at`. See my answer below.

Comment: @wohlstad Thats the only mistake I ve seen. but your answer points other mistakes also. I will thumb up ur answer;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you meant to generate output similar to [`numpy.meshgrid`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html), and [Matlab `meshgrid`](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html).

There are several errors in your code:

1. The `cv::Mat` is initialized with type CV_16U (i.e. 16 bit unsigned value), but when you access the elements with `at` you use `int` (which is 32bit signed).
   You should change it to `at<unsigned short>` (or change the type of the `cv::Mat` to 32 bit signed - `CV_32S`).
2. You initialized the `cv::Mat` with wrong sizes: `xmat` has size of **`(sy, sx)`**, but `ymat` has size of **`(sy, sy)`**.
3. The indices (row, col) you used to access the mat elements were incorrect. To make it easier to use correctly, I changed the names of the dimentions to `rows`, `cols`,
   and the loop indices to `iRow`, `iCol`.
4. The values in the matrices should come from the values in `x` and `y` vectors (not the indices).

See updated code below (and the notes following it regarding the changes):

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

std::pair<cv::Mat, cv::Mat> meshgrid(std::vector<unsigned short> const & x, std::vector<unsigned short> const & y)
{
    int cols = static_cast<int>(x.size());
    int rows = static_cast<int>(y.size());
    cv::Mat xmat(rows, cols, CV_16U);
    cv::Mat ymat(rows, cols, CV_16U);

    for (int iRow = 0; iRow < rows; ++iRow) {
        auto * pRowData = xmat.ptr<unsigned short>(iRow);
        for (int iCol = 0; iCol < cols; ++iCol) {
            pRowData[iCol] = x[iCol];
            std::cout << pRowData[iCol] << "\t";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    for (int iRow = 0; iRow < rows; ++iRow) {
        auto * pRowData = ymat.ptr<unsigned short>(iRow);
        for (int iCol = 0; iCol < cols; ++iCol) {
            pRowData[iCol] = y[iRow];
            std::cout << pRowData[iCol] << "\t";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return std::make_pair(std::move(xmat), std::move(ymat));
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<unsigned short> xxx{ 1,2 };
    std::vector<unsigned short> yyy{ 10,11,12 };
    auto p = meshgrid(xxx, yyy);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1       2
1       2
1       2

10      10
11      11
12      12
```

Some notes:

1. I might have misunderstood which values you wanted to set in the `cv::Mat`'s. But at least now you have code that does not crash. You can change the assigned values as you wish.
2. Using `at` to access `cv::Mat` elements one after the other is very inefficient, because `at` contains some validations for every access.
   It's a lot more efficient to use the `cv::Mat` method `ptr`, that gives you a pointer to the data of a row. Then you can use this pointer to traverse the row more efficiently - see above
3. In any method, it is more efficient to traverse a `cv::Mat` one row after another (and not column by column). This causes you to access continous memory, and decrease the number of cache misses.
4. In your real code, it's better to separate calculations from I/O. Therefore it's better if your `meshgrid` function will only create the matrices. Print them outside if you need.
5. No need to initialize the `cv::Mat`s to ones, because immediatly afterwards we set the values for all elements.
6. In my code `x` and `y` are passed to the function by const refernce. It is more efficient (avoid copy) and also forces the compiler to verify the vectors are not modified.
7. Better to avoid `using namespace std` - see here [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).
   From similar reasons I recomend to avoid `using namespace cv` as well.

Comment: Thank you, your solution is worked, it is because of the discrepancy in data type that cv::Mat gets.